Migrating from pulumi to terraform using azure, subnet Id's starting with '/' cause resources always to be updated when they should not
Since a migration from pulumi to terraform, every time the terraform script is applied azure apps with a subnet configured get updated.
It seems pulumi created them with a / in front of their ids, which terraform does not seem to have. The following msg is displayed for these:
# azurerm_linux_web_app.myWebApp will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "myWebApp" {
        id                                             = "/subscriptions/<subsId>/resourceGroups/<rgName>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/myWebApp"
        name                                           = "myWebApp"
      ~ virtual_network_subnet_id                      = "/subscriptions/<subsId>/resourceGroups/<rgName>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<vnetNAme>/subnets/<subVnetName>" -> "subscriptions/<subsId>/resourceGroups/<rgName>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<vnetNAme>/subnets/<subVnetName>"

It does not seem to have an effect in azure, but I would prefer it to not happen.
Is there a way to adjust the scripts so terraform stops performing this incorrect update?

This kind of issues happened to me many times.
I believe the problem is not the extra / but the casing of characters, i.e. some resource IDs are all lowercase while others have uppercase letters.
Similar issues on Github:

azurerm_api_management stores subnet id as a lowercase string?
AKS OMS LAW ID repetitively updated due to unnecessary case sensibility

Try changing the resource ID that contains some uppercase letters:
subscriptions/<subsId>/resourceGroups/<rgName>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<vnetNAme>/subnets/<subVnetName>

To all lowercase:
/subscriptions/<subsId>/resourcegroups/<rgName>/providers/microsoft.network/virtualnetworks/<vnetName>/subnets/<subVnetName>

Or vice-versa.

Thank you for this, seems plausible. I did however try to do a lower(<subneid>) in there, but with than tf gives us and error about parsing the id The parsed Resource ID was missing a value for the segment at position 2 (which should be the literal value "resourceGroups").. my non-obfuscated ids (from the question) are in the same case at both side of the -> symbol as well.
